# Why is ParentNode is null on dynamically create element added to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have created a custom datepicker that opens when a date input is focused on.  The content inside that datepicker is created dynamically based on the current date.  I want to hide it if someone clicks outside the div, but when I try to determine if the click is inside or outside by using .closest(".date-picker") I get null.  Upon further inspection my date picker doesn't return any ancestors at all, not even parentNode.  Any idea why this would be?

Here is my click event listener to hide the date picker and where I am getting the null for parentNode.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    _initDatePicker(); // <--- dynamically adding elements here

    document.addEventListener("click",
        function (event) {
            var classes = event.target.classList; // <---- this works just fine
            var parent = event.target.parentNode; // <---- returns null

            // If user clicks outside the datepicker window, then close
            if (!event.target.closest(".date-picker")) {
                hideDatePicker();
            }
        },
        false
    );

}, false);
```

Here is my code where I dynamically create the content inside the div and add it to the dom

```
title_element.textContent = "Select Year";
cal_elements.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content

if (!cal_elements.classList.contains('year_list'))
    cal_elements.classList.add('year_list');

for (let i = 0; i < amount_years; i++) {
    let create_year = year - i;

    const element = document.createElement('div'); // Create the new div
    element.classList.add('cal_element');

    if (create_year >= min_year) {
        element.classList.add('text-light');
        element.classList.add('pointer');
        element.textContent = create_year;

        element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            selectedYear = this.innerText;

            selected_date_element.textContent = selectedYear;
            if (date_picker_element.classList.contains('years')) {
                date_picker_element.classList.remove('years');
                date_picker_element.classList.add('months');
            }
            populateDates();
        });
    }

    cal_elements.appendChild(element); // Add div to the DOM
}
```

When clicking on the datepicker, I can get the ClassList of the element that I click on, but I can't get the ParentNode even though it has been added to the DOM

Comment: Have you logged what `event.target` actually is?

Comment: Yes, it returns the correct element that has the correct value, classes, and everything, but both ParentNode and ParentElement are null.

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question, but instead of `if (!event.target.closest(".date-picker")) {` you could use `if (!event.target.classList.contains("date-picker")) {`, which avoids having to access a parent and just checks the clicked item to see if it is not the date picker.

Comment: Are you building the elements dynamically after the DOM has loaded or before? Just checking that perhaps the event listener is being initiated before the elements are appended to the DOM?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'd prefer to use closest so that I don't have to have the date-picker class added to every element in the datepicker.  But that is a good work around if I can't figure out what is causing this problem.

Comment: @sychordCoder I am dynamically creating the elements before I add the event listener.  I edited my question to show where I call _initDatePicker() which creates those elements

Comment: Then use `if (!event.currentTarget.classList.contains("date-picker")) {` which refers to the element that is handling the event, not the element that triggered it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Just tried your recommendation, but it looks like the event isn't bubbling up.

Comment: @package5 I'm encountering this issue as well; both `event.target.contains(".class")` and `event.target.parentNode` come up as null — the workaround I found was to search `event.path` for the parent I need to check, which still seems accessible.